# Trying to load a Bitmap from Resources returns NULL with an error code of 1813

Tags: c++, winapi, resources

I've been trying to load a bitmap from my resources in order to set it as an icon in one of my programs control for a good while now, with no success at all.

What I did so far:

First, I went into the code of my .rc file, and added all my bitmaps like this in the corresponding BMP section. Note that all .bmp files are saved as 256-color-bitmaps:

```
IDB_01d                 BMP                     "<path>"
```

Afterwards, I went into my Resource.h file and inserted a define for every bitmap, looking like this:

```
#define IDB_01d                         2000
```

After adding my resources, this is what I tried in my code so far:

```
HBITMAP hbmp = LoadBitmap(m_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_01d));
DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
m_weatherIcon.SetIcon(hbmp);
```

Note that m_hInstance is the HINSTANCE i got from my _tWinMain-method.

However, this is not working. The problem is currently the fact, that hbmp is NULL, due to LoadBitmap returning a NULL value.

I added a call to get the last error, and the error code I'm getting is 1813 all the time. I already did some research, and it seems like the HINSTANCE might be the problem, but I don't see how exactly.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need declare in .rc file

```
IDB_01d  BITMAP "<path>"
```

but you using unknown resource type `BMP`

Comment: Wow, I never would have suspected that to be the problem! Can't believe I missed that